# Esconder menu JavaScript

Tags: javascript, menu, javascript-eventos

Com o código que eu criei não estou conseguindo esconder o meu menu, mesmo fechando e abrindo o menu hambúrguer e criando o efeito o menu não fica escondido. Poderiam me ajudar e dizer onde estou errando?

```js
var hamburguer = document.querySelector('.hamburguer');
var nav = document.querySelector('.navLinks');
var navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.navLinks li');

/*Funcionalidade do Menu Hamburguer */
function mostrarMenu(){
    hamburguer.addEventListener('click', function () {
        nav.classList.toggle('navAtiva');
    });
}
mostrarMenu();

/*Animação dos links */
function animacao() {
    hamburguer.addEventListener('click', function () {
        navLinks.forEach((link, index) => {
            if (link.style.animation) {
                link.style.animation = '';
            } else {
                link.style.animation = `navLinkDesaparece 0.5s ease forwards ${index / 7 + 0.3}s`;
            }
        });
        hamburguer.classList.toggle('hamburguerAlternar');
    });
}
animacao();
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
} 
nav{
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 0 70px;/*Margem do Logo*/
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(53, 53, 53);
    font-weight: bolder;
    height: 55px;
}
nav img{
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
}
.navLinks{
    float: right;
}
nav ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
}
nav ul li{
    list-style: none;
}
nav ul li a{
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    margin: 0 16px;
    color: #00ced1;
    text-decoration: none;
}
nav ul li a:hover{
    color: #ffffff;
}

.hamburguer{
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
    color: #00ced1;
}
.hamburguer div{
    width: 22px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: rgb(21, 126, 126);
    margin: 5px;
    transition: all 0.6s ease; /*Transition para menu Hamburguer virar X*/
}

@media screen and (max-width: 991px){
    nav{
        padding: 0 20px;
        height: 35px;
    }
    .hamburguer{
        display: block;
    }
    nav img{
        position: absolute;
    }
    nav .navLinks{
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: calc(100vh - 50px);
        background: rgb(53, 53, 53);
        top: 35px;
        left: 0;
        transition: 0.6s;
        font-size: 18px;
    }
    nav ul{
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
    }
}
.navAtiva{
    transform: translate(0%);
}

/*Adicionando animação*/
@keyframes navLinkDesaparece{
    from{
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateX(100px);
    }
    to{
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateX(0px);
    }
}

/*Transformando Menu Hamburguer em X*/
.hamburguerAlternar .linha1{
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(5px, 6px);
} 
.hamburguerAlternar .linha2{
    opacity: 0;
} 
.hamburguerAlternar .linha3{
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(5px, -6px);
} 


/*CAPA*/
```

```html
    <nav>
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="img/thpernomian.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <ul class="navLinks">
            <li><a href="#">Início</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sobre mim</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Portfólio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Hobbies</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contato</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="hamburguer">
            <div class="linha1"></div>
            <div class="linha2"></div>
            <div class="linha3"></div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `.navLinks` (menu) deveria já vir oculto. Acrescente `display: none` na classe:

```
.navLinks{
    float: right;
    display: none;
}
```

Depois basta criar outro *breakpoint* com `min-width: 992px` antes do que já existe de `max-width: 991px`:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 992px){
   .navLinks{
     display: flex;
   }
}
```

Ou seja, se a largura da tela for maior que 991px, o menu volta ao normal e exibe os itens.

Veja:

```js
var hamburguer = document.querySelector('.hamburguer');
var nav = document.querySelector('.navLinks');
var navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.navLinks li');

/*Funcionalidade do Menu Hamburguer */
function mostrarMenu(){
    hamburguer.addEventListener('click', function () {
        nav.classList.toggle('navAtiva');
    });
}
mostrarMenu();

/*Animação dos links */
function animacao() {
    hamburguer.addEventListener('click', function () {
        navLinks.forEach((link, index) => {
            if (link.style.animation) {
                link.style.animation = '';
            } else {
                link.style.animation = `navLinkDesaparece 0.5s ease forwards ${index / 7 + 0.3}s`;
            }
        });
        hamburguer.classList.toggle('hamburguerAlternar');
    });
}
animacao();
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
} 
nav{
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 0 70px;/*Margem do Logo*/
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(53, 53, 53);
    font-weight: bolder;
    height: 55px;
}
nav img{
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
}
.navLinks{
    float: right;
    display: none;
}

nav ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
}
nav ul li{
    list-style: none;
}
nav ul li a{
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    margin: 0 16px;
    color: #00ced1;
    text-decoration: none;
}
nav ul li a:hover{
    color: #ffffff;
}

.hamburguer{
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
    color: #00ced1;
}
.hamburguer div{
    width: 22px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: rgb(21, 126, 126);
    margin: 5px;
    transition: all 0.6s ease; /*Transition para menu Hamburguer virar X*/
}

@media screen and (min-width: 992px){
   .navLinks{
     display: flex;
   }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 991px){
    nav{
        padding: 0 20px;
        height: 35px;
    }
    .hamburguer{
        display: block;
    }
    nav img{
        position: absolute;
    }
    nav .navLinks{
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: calc(100vh - 50px);
        background: rgb(53, 53, 53);
        top: 35px;
        left: 0;
        transition: 0.6s;
        font-size: 18px;
    }
    nav ul.navAtiva{
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
    }
}
.navAtiva{
    transform: translate(0%);
}

/*Adicionando animação*/
@keyframes navLinkDesaparece{
    from{
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateX(100px);
    }
    to{
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateX(0px);
    }
}

/*Transformando Menu Hamburguer em X*/
.hamburguerAlternar .linha1{
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(5px, 6px);
} 
.hamburguerAlternar .linha2{
    opacity: 0;
} 
.hamburguerAlternar .linha3{
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(5px, -6px);
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="logo">
      <img src="img/thpernomian.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <ul class="navLinks">
      <li><a href="#">Início</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sobre mim</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Portfólio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Hobbies</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contato</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="hamburguer">
      <div class="linha1"></div>
      <div class="linha2"></div>
      <div class="linha3"></div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Sam, eu preciso esconder e apresentar o menu quando clico no hambúrguer.

Comment: Então. O código não faz isso?

Comment: O código já apresenta a tela para mobile, quando clico no hambúrguer faz o efeito mas não  removo o menu e não adiciono novamente.

Comment: Pelo que testei aqui tá funcionando normalmente.